# Put some conditions to the date in calender SWT

Tags: java, swt

How can I put some conditions to my calendar in SWT? For example to make the date between 1970 and 2030 and it is not allowed to show in calendar more than this range.

Comment: The date range of the SWT `DateTime` widget cannot be cannot be limited. I suggest to add validation code (e.g. on the `SWT.Selection` event) and show an error label within the dialog/page that holds the date entry field if the date is out of range.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have an internal way to do this. So you can have some condition to check whether the selection date falls between minimum and maximum date and you can throw an error pop up like shown below and you can reset the selection to any date.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DateTime;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

/**
 * The Class RestrictYearInCalender.
 * 
 * @author subash
 */
public class RestrictYearInCalender {

    /** The min date. */
    private static Date minDate;

    /** The max date. */
    private static Date maxDate;

    /** The format. */
    private static SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    /**
     * The main method.
     *
     * @param args the arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("Calender");
        shell.setLayout(new RowLayout());

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        /* Set the minimum */
        cal.set(1970, 0, 0);
        minDate = cal.getTime();

        /* Set the maximum */
        cal.set(2030, 0, 0);
        maxDate = cal.getTime();

        DateTime calendar = new DateTime(shell, SWT.CALENDAR);
        calendar.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
            {
                /* Get the selection from the calender drop down*/
                int day = calendar.getDay();
                int month = calendar.getMonth() + 1;
                int year = calendar.getYear();

                /* Parse the selection */
                Date newDate = null;
                try
                {
                    newDate = format.parse(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
                }
                catch (ParseException e)
                {
                    return;
                }

                /* Compare it to the minimum and maximum */
                if(newDate.after(maxDate) || newDate.before(minDate))
                {
                    /* Set to the maximum or maximum according to requirement*/
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.setTime(minDate);
                    calendar.setMonth(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
                    calendar.setDay(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    calendar.setYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                    MessageDialog.openError(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), "Error", "Range selection should be between 1970-2030");
                }
            }
        });

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

[image: Calender]
[image: Error dialog]